# PowerBI Failed to execute 'atob' on 'Window' in parsePowerBIAccessToken

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

Randomly today my powerbi embedded code has been throwing:

```
DOMException: Failed to execute 'atob' on 'Window': The string to be decoded is not correctly encoded.
at window.atob (eval at <anonymous> (https://app.powerbi.com/13.0.11674.244/scripts/reportembed.externals.bundle.min.js:1326:504), <anonymous>:1:83)
at e.parsePowerBIAccessToken (https://app.powerbi.com/13.0.11674.244/scripts/reportEmbed.min.js:1:2331307)
at e.isTokenTenantValid (https://app.powerbi.com/13.0.11674.244/scripts/reportEmbed.min.js:1:2331046)
at t.isPowerBIAccessTokenValid (https://app.powerbi.com/13.0.11674.244/scripts/reportembed.bundle.min.js:21:31523)
at t.promptForLogin (https://app.powerbi.com/13.0.11674.244/scripts/reportembed.bundle.min.js:21:31233)
at m.scope.promptForLogin (https://app.powerbi.com/13.0.11674.244/scripts/reportembed.bundle.min.js:21:25515)
at fn (eval at compile (https://app.powerbi.com/13.0.11674.244/scripts/reportembed.externals.bundle.min.js:1444:307), <anonymous>:4:374)
at m.$digest (https://app.powerbi.com/13.0.11674.244/scripts/reportembed.externals.bundle.min.js:1350:310)
at https://app.powerbi.com/13.0.11674.244/scripts/reportEmbed.min.js:1:1626830
at t.i [as _next] (https://app.powerbi.com/13.0.11674.244/scripts/reportEmbed.min.js:1:189984)
```

I checked the access token and they appear valid. (No different to the ones working yesterday). I added a debug hook into window.atob and it seems like something inside of parsePowerBIAccessToken is passing undefined to atob. I can't figure out why though unless this code changed.

Kind of stuck on how to figure out the issue. (Not helping that Chrome seems to struggle to debug the lines without crashing).

The code path is trying to run the embed token through this code:

```js
e.prototype.parsePowerBIAccessToken = function() {
    return JSON.parse(atob(i.powerBIAccessToken.split(".")[1]))
}
```

Odd because the code is clearly using "tokenType: models.TokenType.Embed," and thus probably shouldn't be going down that code path?

I noticed it works if I'm logged into the MS account though, so it's using cookies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should always get the embed URL using the REST APIs.

From the [embed for your customers (Embed Token) documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embed-sample-for-customers)

```
using Microsoft.PowerBI.Api.V2;
using Microsoft.PowerBI.Api.V2.Models;

// You need to provide the workspaceId where the dashboard resides.
ODataResponseListReport reports = await client.Reports.GetReportsInGroupAsync(workspaceId);

// Get the first report in the group.
Report report = reports.Value.FirstOrDefault();

// Generate Embed Token.
var generateTokenRequestParameters = new GenerateTokenRequest(accessLevel: "view");
EmbedToken tokenResponse = client.Reports.GenerateTokenInGroup(workspaceId, report.Id, generateTokenRequestParameters);

// Generate Embed Configuration.
var embedConfig = new EmbedConfig()
{
    EmbedToken = tokenResponse,
    EmbedUrl = report.EmbedUrl,
    Id = report.Id
};
```

You get the embed URL from the Report object.

The URL you got from powerbi.com is [powerbi secure embed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-embed-secure) and it is not recommended to use this URL for another scenario.

Comment: I used the rest API method, but this worked. Thank you. This seems like the correct method.

Answer (score 3):

If you copy and paste the embed URL from a report it'll have autoAuth=true in the URL. You must remove this from the embed URL or it attempts to use your cookies to authenticate. (It'll also try to use the embed token like an access token and execute wrong code, so that's MS's bug).

In my JS code I removed the autoAuth from the embed url and it'll skip trying to use cookies.

```
embedURL = embedURL.replace(/autoAuth=true&/ig, '');
```

Comment: Can I ask how you came across this? Our app's reports have been working up until today. It is odd that this query param became an issue all of a sudden.

Comment: I just implemented power bi 2 weeks ago. I had it working because I was logged into the MS account the whole time on the machine I was testing on. When the session timed out it caused the above error. I randomly logged in to check something and noticed it started working again on my local machine. Then it clicked, something must be using a cookie to login rather than the embed token. So I looked at the sample and noticed their embed url does not have the autoAuth part so I removed it and it worked everywhere.

Comment: We never had issues regardless of being logged into PoweBI or not. Anyways, thanks for the find!

Comment: Thank you! thank you! We have no idea why PowerBI changed their API their from under us this week. Their support was completely unresponsive as well. Bless you

Answer (score 0):

We raised this issue with the PowerBI team. You are supposed to use an API call to get the embed URL for a report. There is an API tester here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/reports/getreportingroup

Here is a playground for testing embedding: https://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-JavaScript/demo/v2-demo/index.html